# Is there a simple or lightweight way to test if an Envelope Id is valid (using the Soap API)?

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I have a List of possible Envelope Ids.  Rather than submit each to RequestStatus() and catch an Exception if it's not an actual Envelope Id, is there a (simple / lightweight) way to just get the envelope ids which have been submitted by a given account (or integrator key)?

Currently I'm going thru the entire list at the start of my app, making a few simple syntax checks (e.g. 0-length strings are bad) and tracking which are valid / invalid.  But even though this is a one-time operation, it seems excessively wasteful and expensive.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the equivalent exists in SOAP (doesn't look like it does) but you can make one of your API calls through the DocuSign REST API to retrieve a full set of valid envelopes IDs.  Look at the middle example in the API Walkthroughs, the one titled "Get Status of Envelopes":

http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs

That returns a set of envelopes based on query parameters you pass.  For instance, you can search by date range, or by status changes, etc.  [Here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Status%20Changes.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____38) is the documentation for the call.